# Frequet BSOD, system service, WHEA and KMODE exceptions

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, crash

I've been having frequent BSOD with different codes. The times and reasons for the BSOD are inconsistent. Sometimes I can be watching videos for hours crash free and then it will crash while browsing the web. I can login from startup and then immediately crash. Start  up a video game and then crash. I did some stress tests and overheating doesnt seem to be an issue. Below is a link to about a weeks worth of minidumps.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k5r7n2xo4ff7ioj/AABgYgbLilmEduIDyX6TorSaa?dl=0

I removed my sound card and uninstalled the drivers. I updated my graphics card drivers from the manufacturers website. I also do not overclock. I used blue screen view and whocrashed to see if I could figure out what is going on but I've hit a wall. Also did some verifier tests and once I get the result and fix/remove the driver, I get another one for another reason.

- Operating System

  - Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- CPU

  - AMD FX-8350  24 °C
  - Vishera 32nm Technology
- RAM

  - 8.00 GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 577MHz (11-11-11-28)
- Motherboard

  - ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. M5A99FX PRO R2.0 (Socket 942)  32 °C
- Graphics

  - S27D390 (1920x1080@60Hz)
  - 4095 MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 (Gigabyte)    41 °C
- Storage

  - 931 GB TOSHIBA MKNSSDRE1TB (SSD) 35 °C
- Optical Drives

  - HL-DT-ST BD-RE WH14NS40
- Audio

  - NVIDIA Virtual Audio Device (Wave Extensible) (WDM)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I removed the sound card and got rid of the drivers for that card. I also ran prime 95. I got a lot of errors on the first run and a few fatal errors. In my dropbox link above, I included my prime95 results before I got a BSOD halfway through it and also included that BSOD minidump too. I also ran a windows memory diagnostic and my sticks passed. I do think you are correct about my CPU being bad or very close to being fried. –

Comment: do you have a friend with an AMD FX cpu that you can test. if the PC is now fine, the CPU is damaged

Answer (score 0):

[Analyzing the dump](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) shows this:

the last dump shows CPU Cache failures wile reading data (Data Read):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffffaf09152f0028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000bc800020, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000000120139, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.15063.674 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  To be filled by O.E.M.

SYSTEM_SKU:  SKU

SYSTEM_VERSION:  To be filled by O.E.M.

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  2501

BIOS_DATE:  04/07/2014

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  M5A99FX PRO R2.0

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev 1.xx

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 0

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffaf09152f0028

BUGCHECK_P3: bc800020

BUGCHECK_P4: 120139

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_AuthenticAMD

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: 10ee

CPU_VENDOR:  AuthenticAMD

CPU_FAMILY: 15

CPU_MODEL: 2

CPU_STEPPING: 0

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

STACK_TEXT:
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 hal!HalBugCheckSystem
02 nt!WheaReportHwError
03 hal!HalpMcaReportError
04 hal!HalpMceHandlerCore
05 hal!HalpMceHandler
06 hal!HalHandleMcheck
07 nt!KxMcheckAbort
08 nt!KiMcheckAbort
09 0x0

IMAGE_NAME:  AuthenticAMD

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x124_authenticamd_processor_cache

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {b533751b-676e-7546-bcdc-24e6c40d0064}

---------

4: kd> !errrec ffffaf09152f0028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffffaf09152f0028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d35b71dafae7f3
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 11/12/2017 5:00:03 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffaf09152f00a8
Section       @ ffffaf09152f0180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Data Read
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 1
CPU Version   : 0x0000000000600f20
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000004

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffaf09152f00f0
Section       @ ffffaf09152f0240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000004
CPU Id        : 20 0f 60 00 00 08 08 04 - 0b 32 98 3e ff fb 8b 17
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffffaf09152f0240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffaf09152f0138
Section       @ ffffaf09152f02c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : GCACHEL1_DRD_ERR (Proc 4 Bank 0)
  Status      : 0xbc80002000120139
  Address     : 0x0000000000000003
  Misc.       : 0xc00a0fff00000000
```

this could be bad CPU. Run a load test like Prime95 to check CPU issues.

A different dump shows a failure triggered by `Driver Verifier` for the driver `cthdb.sys` (Soundblaster Audio driver)

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VIOLATION (c4)
A device driver attempting to corrupt the system has been caught.  This is
because the driver was specified in the registry as being suspect (by the
administrator) and the kernel has enabled substantial checking of this driver.
If the driver attempts to corrupt the system, bugchecks 0xC4, 0xC1 and 0xA will
be among the most commonly seen crashes.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000002000, Code Integrity Issue: The caller specified an executable pool type. (Expected: NonPagedPoolNx)
Arg2: fffff80a67d41021, The address in the driver's code where the error was detected.
Arg3: 0000000000000000, Pool Type.
Arg4: 00000000746c6946, Pool Tag (if provided).

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for cthdb.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for cthdb.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.15063.674 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 2000

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff80a67d41021

BUGCHECK_P3: 0

BUGCHECK_P4: 746c6946

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xc4_2000

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: 10ee

CPU_VENDOR:  AuthenticAMD

CPU_FAMILY: 15

CPU_MODEL: 2

CPU_STEPPING: 0

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VERIFIER_ENABLED_VISTA_MINIDUMP

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!VerifierBugCheckIfAppropriate
02 nt!VfReportIssueWithOptions
03 nt!VfCheckPoolType
04 nt!VerifierExAllocatePoolEx
05 cthdb


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
cthdb+1021
fffff80a`67d41021 483bc3          cmp     rax,rbx

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  74c33b48

IMAGE_NAME:  cthdb.sys

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xc4_2000_VRF_cthdb!unknown_function

BUCKET_ID:  0xc4_2000_VRF_cthdb!unknown_function

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0xc4_2000_vrf_cthdb!unknown_function

---------

6: kd> lmvm cthdb
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff80a`67d40000 fffff80a`67d4b000   cthdb    T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: cthdb.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\cthdb.sys
    Image name: cthdb.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Thu Jun 18 08:14:10 2015 (558261B2)
    CheckSum:         00015CDC
    ImageSize:        0000B000
```

[Update the sound driver](http://support.creative.com/Products/Products.aspx?catid=1) and [disable Driver Verifier](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5470-enable-disable-driver-verifier-windows-10-a.html).